# AnchorPane elements ignore Mouse click

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I initialized some elements not my Anchor Pane:

```
AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(listLoader.load(), textareaLoader.load(), fieldLoader.load(), menuLoader.load(), buttonLoader.load());
```

But when I try to click on the MenuBar or the List View it doesn't works. For example, in this case I can click on the buttons (maybe) because it is the last element that I initialize in the AnchorPane constructor. I cannot use a BorderPane or any other Layout, so I need to find a solution with this configuration. 
These are my fxml files: 
**list.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.ListController">
<children>
    <AnchorPane> 
        <children>
            <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="239.0" />
        </children>
    </AnchorPane> 
</children>
```

**menuBar.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="mailbox.MenuBarController">
<children>
    <AnchorPane> 
        <children>
            <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0">
                <menus>
                    <Menu text="File">
                        <items>
                            <MenuItem onAction="#elimina" text="Elimina" />
                        </items>
                    </Menu>
                    <Menu text="Cambia Account">
                        <items>
                            <MenuItem fx:id="email1" text="filippo@hotmail.it" />
                            <MenuItem fx:id="email2" text="giancarlo@yahoo.it" />
                            <MenuItem fx:id="email3" text="alessandro@gmail.it" />
                        </items>
                    </Menu>
                </menus>
            </MenuBar>
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
```

**textArea.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="mailbox.TextAreaController">
<children>
    <AnchorPane> 
        <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="textarea" editable="false" layoutX="246.0" layoutY="255.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="350.0" />
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
```

**button.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.ButtonController">
<children>
    <AnchorPane> 
        <children>
            <Button id="scrivi" layoutX="268.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Scrivi" />
            <Button id="reply" layoutX="342.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Reply" />
            <Button id="replyall" layoutX="420.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Reply-All" />
            <Button id="forward" layoutX="511.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Forward" />
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
```

**textfield.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane mouseTransparent="false" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.TextFieldController">
<children>
    <AnchorPane> 
        <children>
            <TextField fx:id="id" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="39.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="35.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="mitt" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="72.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="182.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="dest" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="108.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="182.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="oggetto" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="144.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="182.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="data" editable="false" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="39.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <Label layoutX="329.0" layoutY="44.0" text="ID:" />
            <Label layoutX="291.0" layoutY="77.0" text="Mittente:" />
            <Label layoutX="398.0" layoutY="44.0" text="Data:" />
            <Label layoutX="268.0" layoutY="113.0" text="Destinatario:" />
            <Label layoutX="292.0" layoutY="149.0" text="Oggetto:" />
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
```

I made them with Scene Builder, I need to keep them separately because I prefer a singular file for each controller.
EDIT:
[image: Output]

EDIT2:
This is the first AnchorPane (on the right you can see the settings):
[image: SB1]
This is the second AnchorPane
[image: SB2]
This is the Textarea:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you use `BorderPane` or any other `layout` ?

Comment: Because I should re-design all the application and modify all the fxml files. With the AnchorPane, as you can see, I already positioned all the elements where I need them to be

Comment: Try adding an mouse event filter to the window to see what the actual `EventTarget` is. If it isn't the `ListView` or one of its children then you likely have some node overlapping it.

Comment: @Slaw With "overlapping" you mean that there is one element on another one? Because I tried to add them singularly and if I set the first two elements it works, but as soon as I set the text area and the textfield I cannot click anymore on the first two elements. I'm gonna edit the question to show you the output of the application.

Comment: Some node may still be overlapping the other nodes, even if you can't see it. Add the code used to load the FXML files so we can run/debug your application on our own machines  (i.e.  include a [mcve]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AnchorPane` is one of the worst layouts, if you're designing a responsive layout, since it does not allow you to take the size of other children into account, when positioning a child (except if you use listeners/bindings to update layout parameters).

Your problem in this specific case is that your `button.fxml` covers all the content of the other fxmls and therefore receives all the `MouseEvent`s. To visualize the area the fxml covers, just add this attribute to the root of `button.fxml`: `style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)"`.

A possible workaround would be making the child fxmls as small as possible and specifying the root position in the parent:

Identify the minimum `layoutX` and `layoutY` of the children of the inner `<AnchorPane>`, set those values for the root (or add them to previous values of the root) and subtract these values from all children of the the inner `<AnchorPane>`.

```xml
<!-- specify min layoutX/Y as position for root -->
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    layoutX="268"
    layoutY="200"
    fx:controller="mailbox.ButtonController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane>
            <children>
                <!-- subtract root layoutX/Y from positions -->
                <Button id="scrivi" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0"
                    prefWidth="65.0" text="Scrivi" />
                <Button id="reply" layoutX="74" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Reply" />
                <Button id="replyall" layoutX="152" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Reply-All" />
                <Button id="forward" layoutX="243" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Forward" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

(Proceed accordingly with the other fxmls.)

It is still a terrible idea overlay nodes this way, since you're using absolute positions and any modification of one of the fxmls could require you to update multiple others to avoid overlays. Even worse looks different depending on the OS/settings. For one OS the scene could look fine, on another one one your nodes could overlap.
For this reason I recommend avoiding using absolute positioning, unless you're 100% sure the node sizes are known. A scene like the one shown is better created using `BorderPane`/`HBox`/`VBox` and/or `GridPane`...

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the only thing I cannot select is the list view, if I understood your code correctly, you've set the dimension of the AnchorPane by looking at where the first button is? So for the list view I should select a layoutX="1.0"and a  layoutY="31.0"?

Comment: @SamoaJoe `button.fxml` is just the topmost child. You need to make sure no child after the one containing the `ListView` covers the `ListView`. This is done by identifying the leftmost coordinate (minimum `layoutX`) and topmost coordinate (minimum `layoutY`), setting these values for the fxml root and subtracting them from the properties of all elements contained in the pane.

Comment: And should I consider the prefHeight and the prefWidth of the elements? Or just the layouts?

Comment: We're trying to find the appropriate top left coordinate of the container, so no, width and height are irrelevant.

Comment: I found the problem, which is the textArea. I tried to edit it like this `<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.TextAreaController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane>
            <children>
                <TextArea id="textarea" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="255.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="330.0" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>` <br> In Scene Builder it shows that the AnchorPane is way bigger that the textarea. I'm gonna edit the question to show you the problem